# Can a text file be recovered only from the .*.swp file?

Tags: swap-file, crash-recovery

I was remotely editing a new file: `man-01-Intro.txt` but the machine went
down before I wrote it to disk so only the swp version was conserved. Is there anything that I can do to recover the work already done?

I'm using Vim 7.4.273

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit the same file again.  Vim will prompt you with a few options; say you want to *Recover*.  Then save the file, quit Vim, and remove the swap file (otherwise Vim will prompt you again the next time you edit the same file).  The result may or may not have your latest edits, but it's better than nothing.  Do check that everything is ok.

Comment: I tried before asking. The problem is that the text file never was created, so vim identifies it as a new file and the .swp file is not recognized. *NOT* You are right: I was trying a different directory. Solved! Thanks.